# ruby on rails: vote/unvote using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using acts_as_votable for my voting system in ruby. Right now I can vote/downvote and update the counter. But what I want is to vote, and then downvote and vote again for example, but I can only do that with refreshing. And if I vote and then downvote, how can I update the vote counter to "-1"?

controller:

```
  def upvote
    @improvement_action.upvote_from current_user  #, :vote_scope => 'upvote'
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { count: @improvement_action.get_upvotes.size } }
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
    end
  end

  def downvote
    @improvement_action.downvote_from current_user#, :vote_scope => 'upvote'

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { count: @improvement_action.get_downvotes.size } }
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
    end
  end
```

view:

```
<%= link_to like_improvement_action_path(improvement_action), class:"btn btn-default stat-item like", method: :put, remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %>
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="like_number"> <%= improvement_action.get_upvotes.size %></span>
                    <% end %>

   <%= link_to unlike_improvement_action_path(improvement_action), class:"btn btn-default stat-item downvote", method: :put, remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %>
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="unlike_number"> <%= improvement_action.get_downvotes.size %></span>
                    <% end %>
```

and the application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.like')
    .on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) {
        $('.like_number').html(data.count)

    })
    .on('ajax:send', function () {
        $(this).addClass('loading');
    })
    .on('ajax:complete', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
    })
    .on('ajax:error', function (e, xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    })

$('.downvote')
    .on('ajax:success', function (e, data, status, xhr) {

        $('.unlike_number').html(data.count);


    })
    .on('ajax:send', function () {
        $(this).addClass('loading');
    })
    .on('ajax:complete', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
    })
    .on('ajax:error', function (e, xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

Comment: Is a person allowed to vote and then downvote at the same time, or do you disable the downvote button once the user clicks on upvote?

Comment: yes the person can upvote and then downvote

Comment: What happens to the upvote count if a person upvotes and then downvote. Does the upvote count is reduced by 1 and downvote count is increased by 1.

Comment: yes, like that. the system is like this: http://oi68.tinypic.com/v7fdpl.jpg

Comment: Is the second click on upvote getting registered, I mean does it show anything in the terminal? Or is it only a front end issue where you are unable to update the view?

Comment: it only registers the first clicks, if I upvote and then downvote it stays on downvote. but if I upvote -> downvote -> upvote, it stays neither in up or down. and its not updating the counter if I upvote -> downvote (the upvote dont update the counter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating two files upvote.js.erb and downvote.js.erb and then adding the behaviour which you expect to happen in this file.

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).on('click', '.like', function ( {
        $(this).addClass('loading');
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.downvote' ,function (){
        $(this).addClass('loading');
    });
});
```

upvote.js.erb:(file name should be same as the method in controller)

```
$('.like').removeClass('loading');
 //updated the below lines in both upvote.js.erb and downvote.js.erb
$('.like_number').html('<%= @improvement_action.get_upvotes.size %>');
$('.unlike_number').html('<%= @improvement_action.get_downvotes.size %>');
```

downvote.js.erb:

```
$('.downvote').removeClass('loading');
$('.like_number').html('<%= @improvement_action.get_upvotes.size %>');
$('.unlike_number').html('<%= @improvement_action.get_downvotes.size %>');
```

Comment: its not doing anything when I upvote/downvote :/ and If I refresh the vote is there

Comment: Update all the lines like this: $('.like_number').html('<%= @improvement_action.get_upvotes.size %>');, adding inverted commas in html('').

Comment: Does it show error in terminal or browser's console when you click on upvote, downvote. I guess it might be showing some error in terminal when you click on upvote. Let me know the error.

Comment: it shows no error neither in terminal or browser console

Comment: Can you add a print statement in both .js.erb files and check terminal to check if the count is increasing or not?

Comment: I think its not entering in upvote.js.erb and downvote.js.erb

Comment: Just add one more line in both methods, format.js, in terminal you will be able to see the request is getting processed as js or html.

Comment: its changing all the buttons numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109566/discussion-between-sahil-and-terrorista).